# Can you help me store b2Vec2 in an NSArray?

Tags: c++, objective-c, nsarray

I made an `NSArray` which has some `b2Vec2` (C++) objects in it. I used the following code:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
b2Vec2 verts[] = {
    b2Vec2(28.3f / PTM_RATIO, 80.3f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(7.1f / PTM_RATIO, 89.4f / PTM_RATIO)
};

[array addObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:verts]];
```

Then, I read out `b2Vec2` objects from the `NSArray` like so:

```
NSValue *val = [array objectAtIndex:0];
b2Vec2 *verts;
[val getValue:&verts];
b2Vec2 vec = verts[0];
```

I saw the `x` and `y` values from the `vector` object, but it has confusing values.

For example, `PTM_RATIO = 32` so `28.3f / PTM_RATIO = 0.884375` but the vector has an x value of 4.3629125e-38.

I want to return the `verts` object in its original C++ form, as a `b2Vec2` array. How can I do this?

Comment: No, I don't think anyone has any idea what you're talking about. But if the code above is literally what you did, I'm not surprised it's failing.

Comment: Is it wrong to add b2Vec2 value into NSArray? What's the wrong part of it?

Comment: Where is your array allocated?  What is its lifetime?

Comment: I edited it. Does it still have problems?

Comment: In spades.  The declaration of b2Vec2 is apparently in your procedure, meaning that it's an automatic variable.  As soon as that procedure returns the data is overwritten.  You should allocate the array in either static storage or heap storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your verts as in an NSValue as CGPoints and store that in the array.  Then translate to a b2Vec2 when you need it.

//

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

CGPoint vert1 = CGPointMake(28.3f / PTM_RATIO, 80.3f / PTM_RATIO);
CGPoint vert2 = CGPointMake(7.1f / PTM_RATIO, 89.4f / PTM_RATIO);
[array addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:vert1]];
[array addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:vert2]];
```

then retrieve

```
NSValue *vert1val = [array objectAtIndex:0];
NSValue *vert2val = [array objectAtIndex:1];


b2Vec2 b2vert1 = [vert1val CGPointValue];
b2Vec2 b2vert2 = [vert2val CGPointValue];
```

For fun, and share back with us, you can try storing the `b2Vec2` directly into the `NSValue` objects considering they are the same structures underneath.
As far as storing an array of structures directly into the NSValue, I have never seen that done before

Answer (score 1):

putting pointer into a NSArray is probable not a good idea because you are adding just the pointers to the array no the actual data, try copying or initialising your b2Vec2 array into a NSData or NSMutableData and then add them to your array.

```
[array addObject:[NSData dataWithBytes:verts length:sizeof(b2Vec2)*2]];
```

...

```
b2Vec2 * vl = (b2Vec2*)[[array objectAtIndex:0] bytes];
b2Vec2 vec = vl[0];
```

Comment: NSData *d = [NSData dataWithBytes:&verts length:sizeof(verts)];